# Facebook Feed Dialog error 191

Tags: javascript, facebook, dialog, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-feed

So, I'm trying to make Facebook Feed Dialog to work through Their API but had no success on it so far.

I'm using Facebook Javascript SDK to do it, and the FB.ui method.

```
<script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
                appId      : 'MY FB APP ID',
                xfbml      : true,
                version    : 'v2.3'
            });
        };

        (function(d, s, id){
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function fbShare(url, title, descr, image) {
            FB.ui({
                method: 'feed',
                name: title,
                link: url,
                caption: 'Title',
                description: descr,
                picture: image,
                display: 'popup',
                redirect_uri: url
            },
            function(response) {
                if (response && response.post_id) {
                    //alert('Post was published.');
                } else {
                    //alert('Post was not published.');
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

This is how my link looks like:

```
<a href="javascript:fbShare('http://mywebsite.com/avaliacao/9d8ee3cb3ad759b134da94802e7c49c8', 'My Site Has a new share', 'Lorem ipsum is a pseudo-Latin text used in web design, typography, layout, and printing in place of English to emphasise design elements over content.', 'http://mywebsite.com.br/img/fb-share.png')">Share</a>
```

The error given when I click the share link:

> An error occurred. Please try again later.
>
> API Error Code: 191.
>   API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application.
>   Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by the application."

Comment: right now we only know "it does not work", which is not a good error description. any errors in the console? did you start debugging? where exactly is the problem?

Comment: I'm adding to the original post the error given on the popup when I try to share something.

Comment: better edit your question with that information, as it´s the most important piece of your problem.

Comment: Done. Now the error given by the application is on the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended using another way to use the Feed Dialog.

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function fbShare(url, title, descr, image, winWidth, winHeight) {
    var winTop = (screen.height / 2) - (winHeight / 2);
    var winLeft = (screen.width / 2) - (winWidth / 2);
    window.open('https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=APP-ID
        &name=' + title
        + '&picture=' + image
        + '&caption=My+Caption
        &display=popup' + '
        &description=' + descr + '
        &link=' + url + '
        &redirect_uri=http://mywebsite.com.br/fb-close-popup-window',
        'sharer',
        'top=' + winTop + ',
        left=' + winLeft + ',
        toolbar=0,
        status=0,
        width=' + winWidth + ',
        height=' + winHeight);
}
</script>
```

HTML

```
<a href="javascript:fbShare('http://mywebsite.com/9d8ee3cb3ad759b134da94802e7c49c8','My Site Has a new share','Lorem ipsum is a pseudo-Latin text used in web design, typography, layout, and printing in place of English to emphasise design elements over content.','http://mywebsite.com.br/img/fb-share.png',520, 350)">Share</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `redirect_url` and try again. Or make sure to add the domain of the `redirect_url` as Website platform in the App Settings (http://mywebsite.com/).

Comment: Tried without the 'redirect_url' option. Same error.

Comment: and did you try adding your website in the app settings?

Comment: and i don´t think it will be the same error message if you remove the redirect_uri. it just can´t be.

Comment: Yes, the same error.

And I already added the website under app settings.

Comment: can i get a test link?